# Are there materials for which mechanical stress depends on higher-order derivatives of time than strain rate?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, continuum-mechanics

I've only ever seen it said that mechanical stress depends on strain or strain rate (or both?) and I'm wondering if there are any materials/consitutive equations which involve higher-order derivatives of the strain.

Thanks

Comment: Viscoelastic fluids and solids depend on higher order time derivatives, particularly differential models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are elasticity theories that include higher-order derivatives in the elastic potential energy. These theories are normally called strain-gradient theories. One of the simplest is the couple stress theory.

Comment: Couple stress theory or Cosserat's elasticity are not based on derivatives of strain tensor. These theories typically include additional tensors representing the configurations and deformation of the microstructure: they are based in including new degrees of freedom, not in including higher derivatives of strain.

Comment: There are two different branches. One of them includes higher order derivatives. I suggest that you check ["Effects of couple-stresses in linear elasticity"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00253946) by Mindlin and Tiers ten. If my recollection is correct, the original work by the Cosserat brothers did not include constitute relationships, so it encompasses both approaches. Also, most of the literature uses "Cosserat" to refer to Micropolar elasticity, not just the appearance of a couple-stress tensor.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It’s called nonlinear stress-strain, which technically every material has after the elastic deformation is over.

And if it’s in the elastic portion of the stress-strain curve, then it is called a “nonlinear elastic” material and has nonlinear elasticity.

Every material is very nonlinear once plastic (permanent) deformation starts. Of course. And obviously, nothing is *perfectly* linear; it’s just a matter of whether constant modulus of elasticity can be reasonably assumed over the deformation and duration of the specific application. Many materials are very close to linear over most of their elastic region.

As mentioned some are also “nonlinear elastic” in that the elasticity changes even in the elastic region of deformation. It is usually concave meaning it becomes slightly easier to deform as you go, but it will still go back to its original shape if you let go. There are two elasticities that are used; the tangent elasticity and the secant elasticity. If the deformation is expected to be small then you are in a linear region near zero and use the tangent to that curve. If the deformation is expected to be large, but still elastic, you don’t want to use the tangent at the point where you will be because that just gives you the elasticity for an infinitesimal change right there, you want to use the second elasticity which is just average stress over strain to the point. So they graph just the secant (average) elasticity sometimes.

Many plastics and almost all foams are non-linear elastic. Plastics in particular have a region where it’s just linear from zero for a while, and then it starts to curve a little bit and become more elastic later in the elastic region. Foams get *much* more elastic as you go. Despite no plastic deformation occurring, foams will unload along a different path than the original elastic deformation was. You get back less work than you put in. I’m 99% sure this is a type of “hysteresis” but don’t feel like googling. It heats up for one thing, maybe only. If not then subsequent loadings would be different. Dunno.

In most applications we only look at the elastic portion, because after all you’ve started failure if you’re past that. But not all, of course for example if you were going to be calculating cold working of metal then you have plastic deformation. There are limited applications for exactly how things plasticly deform, and most of those applications are manufacturing because you intend to permanently change the material, but since you can usually just try it out there’s no reason for endless analysis.

Another exception is composite materials. They have complicated stress train curves where part of it is beginning to give and part of it is not etc. etc. Laminates have *both* nonlinear elastic regions first, and then complex nonlinear semi-failure then full failure plastic regions.

I think it’s important to note that all solids respond nonlinearly; it’s just a matter of whether the nonlinearity can be ignored and if elasticity is a reasonable assumption over the given time span.

An engineer very familiar with how nonlinear elastic materials work made this flow chart for picking materials if you ever wonder that you might want one: https://enterfea.com/nonlinear-material-flow-chart/

And he wrote an article which Im sure is good if you want more: https://enterfea.com/difference-between-linear-and-nonlinear-elastic-material/

Comment: 1) I think it’s important to note that *all* solids respond nonlinearly; it’s just a matter of whether the nonlinearity can be ignored and if elasticity is a reasonable assumption over the given time span. 2) I don’t know what “more elastic” means; the term is ambiguous. Do you mean more compliant? Or stiffer? Or something else?

Comment: I made those changes